# What should I write in between parentheses to define the data type I want a variable to change to?

Tags: c

If I have a variable as `float var1 = 157.1;` and want to transform it in int I would do `int var2 = (int)var1;`

I want to know about the other types of data, such as `long int`, `short int`, `unsigned short int`, `long double` and so on.

I tried `long int var2 = (long int)var1;` and it seemed to work, but I'm not sure if it is syntactically correct. If it is, I assume it'd be the same for all the other types, i.e., just the data type and its attributes separated by a space. If it isn't I'd like to know if there's a list of them of some sort.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. Are you asking generally about type casting? This follows the general pattern of `X y = (X) z` where `X` is some C type. If you're not sure if the syntax is correct, *try compiling it* with all warnings turned on (`-Wall` in many compilers) to find out.

Comment: Yes, didn't know the specific term.

Comment: my question was if types as long type which have two words could go in the parentheses?

Comment: This: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-in-a/0596006977/ch04.html contains information you might find interesting.

Comment: Anything can go in there *if* it a valid C type, so `long*` or `unsigned long long` are all fine.

Comment: "I'm not sure if it is syntactically correct." The compiler will complain very loudly if your code is not perfectly syntactically correct. Like a petulant child, it will refuse to run your code at all.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's more like a governmental agency that refuses to accept your form because you filled it out in the wrong colour of ink.

Comment: @tadman your answer was quite useful and informative, however what answered my question specifically was in your comment in 

"Anything can go in there if it a valid C type, so long* or unsigned long long are all fine"

so if you update your answer I can accept it

Comment: Added a note to the answer focusing on that aspect.

Comment: In general you should avoid casting types. There are valid cases, but you must ensure the type you are casting too is capable of holding the data you want to reference as that type to prevent truncation, or just flat undefined behavior. Each type has a max/min for example [Range of an Integer Type](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Range-of-Type.html). Cast with care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the C cast operator, but the operation is more generally "type casting", "casting", or "recasting". This is a directive to the compiler to request a specific conversion.

When casting any valid C type can be specified, so:

```
int x = 10;
unsigned long long y = (unsigned long long) x;
```

In many cases this conversion can be done implicitly, automatically, so it's not always necessary but in others you must force it. For example:

```
int x = 10;
float y = x; // Valid, int -> float happens automatically.
```

You can get caught by surprise though:

```
int x = 10;
float y = x / 3; // y = 3.0, not 3.333, since it does integer division before casting
```

Where you need to cast to get the right result:

```
int x = 10;
float y = (float) x / 3; // 3.33333...
```

Note that when using pointers this is a whole different game:

```
int x = 10;
int* px = &x;
float* y = (float*) px; // Invalid conversion, treats int as a float
```

Generally C trusts you to know what you're doing, so you can easily shoot yourself in the foot. What "compiles" is syntactically valid by definition, but executing properly without crashing is a whole other concern. Anything not specified by the C "rule book" (C standard) is termed [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so you'll need to be aware of when you're breaking the rules, like in that last example.

Sometimes breaking the rules is necessary, like the [Fast Inverse Square Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) which relies on the ability of C to arbitrarily recast values.

Comment: It is not formally called "type casting". That phrase appears nowhere in the C standard. Note that for numeric types no cast is generally necessary; `int x = 42; double y = x;` is perfectly valid, and performs an implicit conversion.

Comment: @KeithThompson What's a more appropriate term here?

Comment: @KeithThompson The [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) (§6.5.4) speaks only to the "cast operator" which is what this is specifically.

Comment: The parenthesized type name is a "cast operator". The expression that includes a cast operator is a *cast-expression* (though for technical reasons that grammatical term applies to expressions that do not include a cast operator). The operation can be called "casting", "conversion", or "explicit conversion". I personally tend to avoid the term "type casting"; that's something that happens to actors, and the word "type" doesn't add any meaning.